# DropDownButton items in a variable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to store the possible values for a DropDownButton in a variable.

**Goal:**
On the press of a button, I want a new list of Strings to be created and assigned as possible choices for the DropdownButton. To do so, I need to store the possible choices (list of DropdownMenuItem) in a variable.

This sample of code works:

```
static String defaultDropDownValue = 'Select your Network';
String dropdownValue = defaultDropDownValue;
[...]
new Flexible(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                      _checkSsid();
                    },
                    items: <String>[defaultDropDownValue, 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
                        .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
            ),
[...]
```

Now, this sample of code does not work:

```
static String defaultDropDownValue = 'Select your Network';
String dropdownValue = defaultDropDownValue;
List<DropdownMenuItem> dropdownList = [defaultDropDownValue, 'one', 'two'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList();
[...]
new Flexible(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                      _checkSsid();
                    },
                    items: dropdownList,
                  ),
            ),
[...]
```

The compiler returns the following error message:

> Error: The argument type 'Null Function(String)' can't be assigned to
>   the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'. Try changing the type of
>   the parameter, or casting the argument to 'void Function(dynamic)'.
>                       onChanged: (String newValue) {

I don't really understand the meaning of the message, nor its cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becasue you don't explicitly define the Type for array in the second example,

You could try `DropdownMenuItem<String>` and `DropdownButton<String>` to explicit them.

```dart
static String defaultDropDownValue = 'Select your Network';
String dropdownValue = defaultDropDownValue;
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> dropdownList = [defaultDropDownValue, 'one', 'two'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      value: value,
      child: Text(value),
    );
  }).toList();
[...]
new Flexible(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    onChanged: (String newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                      _checkSsid();
                    },
                    items: dropdownList,
                  ),
            ),
[...]
```

Referenced from [DropdownButton's Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) below:

> The type T is the type of the value that each dropdown item represents. All the entries in a given menu must represent values with consistent types. Typically, an enum is used. Each DropdownMenuItem in items must be specialized with that same type argument.

Comment: You could mark as answer, let others know this is sloved :)